# Appending Props in React-Redux Form using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux, axios

I have an action that returns dispatch. Right now i am posting props... but i'd like to add a few peices like (uname, role, etc) to the request. What is he easiest way to do so?

I thought something like:

```
const addlFields = { username: 'newTester', role: 'moderator' }
```

Any good advice on how to get this done? Im assuming it is not an axios issue since axios and accepting the props obj.

My request

```
const sendMessageRequest = axios.post(`${POST_MSG_URL}`, props)
  .then(response => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(
          { type: POST_MESSAGE,
            payload: sendMessageRequest
          }
        );
    }
  });`
```

Comment: do these fields (uname, role, etc) need to be provided for every request? If so, you might want to consider a middleware layer

Comment: Yes they are... They are posting a unique message therefore both need to be sent. I tried this with redux-form as well.